# ImageMagick fails rendering of text in svg files

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am getting the trouble about imagick read svg text, like this:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$svgroot = $xmlDoc->createElement('svg');
$textnode = $xmlDoc->createElement('text');
$textnode->setAttribute('font-size','24');
$textnode->setAttribute('transform','matrix(3.1054,0,0,3.1054,158.5,0)');
$textnode->setAttribute('font-family','helvetica');
$textnode->appendChild($xmlDoc->createTextNode("eeee"));

$textnode = $svgroot->appendChild($textnode);
$xmlDoc->appendChild($svgroot);

$svgtext = new Imagick();
$svgtext->setbackgroundcolor('#00000000');

$svgtext->readImageBlob($xmlDoc->saveXML());
```

it will throw an exception at last line readImageBlob function ("helvetica" font is already installed in windows/fonts.).
it says:

```
  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'must specify image size `C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/magick-270886DDFFPHkGTr' @ error/mvg.c/ReadMVGImage/185' in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\imagicktest.php:106 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\imagicktest.php(106): Imagick->readimageblob('<?xml version="...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\imagicktest.php on line 106
```

this bug only under windows server 2003. when imageMagic run under winXP will not throw this exception.
I think this bug is similar as https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=193474

May be windows2003 need install something to support imagick render svg font?

Answer (score -1):

The `ImagickException` is thrown as image size attributes are missing from the root `svg` element. Different version of ImageMagick & SVG system library would contribute to the behavior your experiencing. To fix this -- simply specify the image dimensions with the `viewBox`, `x`, & `y` attributes.

```php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$svgroot = $xmlDoc->createElement('svg');
$svgroot->setAttribute('viewBox','0 0 60 24'); // Set the viewable canvas
$svgroot->setAttribute('x',0);                 // Left offset
$svgroot->setAttribute('y',16);                // Top offset 
$svgroot->setAttribute('width',60);            // Optional rendering width
$svgroot->setAttribute('hieght',24);           // Optional rendering height
```

Comment: thanks for your help, when I set the width and height,the bug was fixed. But when textnode setAttribute('font-family','someFontsName'),the text will not be render to cavans, when I remove the font-family node, the text will appear with no style. May be it is SVG system library wrong(I use ImageMagick 6.8.3)?By the way,if the svg has <image> node,the image will also can't be rendered. How can I change the SVG system library under windows2003? I am despair...

Comment: Font-family should be set within the style attribute. See [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html) & [Fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html). ie: `setAttribute('style','font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;')`. For system library under windows2003, [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a good place to start.